# Data Structure to do lookup on large number

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, radix-tree

I have a requirement to do a lookup based on a large number. The number could fall in the range 1 - 2^32. Based on the input, i need to return some other data structure. My question is that what data structure should i use to effectively hold this?

I would have used an array giving me O(1) lookup if the numbers were in the range say, 1 to 5000. But when my input number goes large, it becomes unrealistic to use an array as the memory requirements would be huge.

I am hence trying to look at a data structure that yields the result fast and is not very heavy.

Any clues anybody?

EDIT:

It would not make sense to use an array since i may have only 100 or 200 indices to store.

Abhishek

Comment: Why does an array become unrealistic? the memory requirements depend completely on the object you are storing, an array has no overhead on your memory in that case.

Comment: I think you're looking for a hash table. std::map<int, otherDataStructure> sound right? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: @Giel It depends on the density as well.  If the numbers are in the range 1-2^32, and there are only 2 or three elements, and array isn't the solution.  If there are 2^32-2 of them, it is.

Comment: Oh right, misread it. Thanks @JamesKanze :) Yeah a std:map or equivalent will do

Comment: [Self-balancing binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)

Comment: @prettycooldevguy: `std::map` is an associative container but it's not a hash table. That would be `std::unordered_map`

Comment: @Blastfurnace - good to know, I've always referred to all associative containers as "hash tables". Probably a habit I should quit :)

Comment: If the data is static, then a binary chop in an auxiliary vector of pointers, sorted by the index is pretty light-weight.

Comment: If the data is static and you really need O(1) access, you could use a [perfect hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). The [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) tool will generate a perfect hash for you and output C source code.

Answer (score 1):

unordered_map or map, depending on what version of C++ you are using.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

---

A simple solution in C, given you've stated at most 200 elements is just an array of structs with an index and a data pointer (or two arrays, one of indices and one of data pointers, where index[i] corresponds to data[i]).  Linearly search the array looking for the index you want.  With a small number of elements, (200), that will be very fast.

Comment: There is also CPP Reference site, which is more accurate: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: Unfortunately OP had incorrectly tagged their question - they are looking for a solution in C!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is a [Judy Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array), which is a sparse associative array. There is a [C Implementation](http://judy.sourceforge.net/) available. I don't have any direct experience of these, although they look interesting and could be worth experimenting with if you have the time.

Another (probably more orthodox) choice is a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Hash tables are data structures which map keys to values, and provide fast lookup and insertion times (provided a good hash function is chosen). One thing they do not provide, however, is ordered traversal.

There are many C implementations. A quick Google search turned up [uthash](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/) which appears to be suitable, particularly because it allows you to use any value type as the key (many implementations assume a string as the key). In your case you want to use an integer as the key.